# Show different Images on 3 Different monitors

Tags: php

I am working on a project where on one computer there are 3 different monitors connected, what i am stuck with it is i want to show 3 different images `<url>` on 3 differnet monitors every-time page is refreshed. I am not sure if this is possible as randomly i know i can do the random part but not sure about the 3 different Images on 3 Different monitors. here is my code.

```
<?php
$xml=("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: There's no way for PHP to know anything about what monitor its results are displayed on; you'll have to send *some* information from the client to the server, e.g. `mypage.php?monitor=1`

Comment: php does not know where and how you are displaying the info you requested from it. you have to differentiate somehow requests from different browser windows opened on different monitors, send some data with each request which will define the monitor.

Comment: I dont have control over the Rss Feeds

Comment: @user580950 It is not a control over the feeds. It is the way how something, that makes requests to php, will tell it which monitor it uses. Otherwise - there is no way to determine which monitor is used in current request.

Comment: @Cheery I just checked that i have control over the RSS feeds, so everything i have to send mypage.php?monitor=1 to check which monitor is calling the RSS feeds?

Comment: @user580950 The program (probably browser) that displays information on specific monitor should send information, as it was showed above, for example, what monitor it uses. Your php code gets this info and returns info specific for that monitor only. So, if browser makes a request `mypage.php?monitor=1`, your script `mypage.php` checks `$_GET['monitor']` and if it is == 1, then returns only info for that "first" monitor. Program that uses another monitor make requests as `mypage.php?monitor=2` and so on.